# JiraXray RestAPI login with Playwright

Tags: javascript, cypress, playwright, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I am new to Playwright , I need to extract sessionId in JiraXray RestAPI ,
but I am getting 403/401 , Basic credentials is not reaching request , can someone help me on Playwright Request for Basic Auth

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -u jira_username:jira_password https://jiraserver.example.com/rest/raven/1.0/api/test/CALC-1880/step
```

playwright.config.j

```
    httpCredentials: {
                   username: "username",
                   password: "pwd123"
               },
```

test.spec.js

```
    const context = await browser.newContext({
                        httpCredentials: {username: 'username', password: 'pwd123'}
                    });
        
                    let sessionid= await context.request.get('https://jiraserver.example.com/rest/auth/1/session');
                expect(sessionid).toBeTruthy();
```

getting 403 , username password is not passed

In works fine in Cypress as below

```
cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        form: true,
        url: 'https://jiraserver.example.com/rest/auth/1/session',
        auth: {
            username: 'username',
            password: 'pwd123',
        },
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        }
```

Comment: Q. I'm not sure what you're ultimately trying to achieve. Can you please elaborare? Do you want to obtain info from test steps?

Comment: I am trying to connect to jira & get JSession  from api https://jiraserver.example.com/rest/auth/1/session

Comment: I understand what you're doing, but exactly what is your purpose?  I ask this so we can properly help you out. It seems you're trying to access the test steps info of a manual test from playwright side.. is that it? But what's your goal/use case?

Comment: To update jira test status based on playwright test info

Comment: In that case, a simpler approach could be to write your tests in Playwright, run them and generate a JUnit XML report; and then upload it to Xray, to the JUnit endpoint. Please have a look at this tutorial and see if it helps: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+web+applications+using+Playwright